# Which of the 'MySQL-Python' connector should I install?

Tags: python, mariadb

I use MariaDB 10, and I had installed the `mysql-connector-python` on CentOS server for over a year.
Also I had installed on my Mac.

Now I formatted the two machines, and can not install on anyone.

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python
```

[image: sudo pip install mysql-connector-python ERROR]

```
pip search mysql | grep python
```

[image: pip search mysql | grep python]

Which of connectors should I install? and how to install?
And how should I install?
In CentOS and tried:

```
sudo yum -y install MySQL-python perl-DBD-MySQL php-mysql postfix
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

And appear this error:

[image]

On my Mac I have the same problem with `mysql-connector-python-rf`.

**UPDATED**
[image: sudo yum install mysql-community-release ERROR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html):

**Installing Connector/Python on Linux Using the MySQL Yum Repository**

For EL6 or EL7-based platforms and Fedora 19 or 20, you can install Connector/Python using the MySQL Yum repository (see Installing Additional MySQL Products and Components with Yum). You must have the MySQL Yum repository on your system's repository list (for details, see Adding the MySQL Yum Repository). To make sure that your Yum repository is up-to-date, use this command:

```
shell> sudo yum update mysql-community-release
```

Then install Connector/Python as follows:

```
shell> sudo yum install mysql-connector-python
```

I am using this on Fedora, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, but, does not work: sudo yum install mysql-community-release
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
No package mysql-community-release available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: And `sudo yum install mysql-connector-python`?

Comment: In CentOS works :) Thanks... now I will try in Mac :)

Comment: In CentOS 7, only works after you install EPEL repository ( sudo yum install -y epel-release )

Comment: Now I have started use anaconda, and to install this connector I only executed:
$ conda install mysql-connector-python